# How to use Rolle's theorem to verify the following?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

How to use Rolle's theorem to verify the location of roots ?

$f(x)=x^3+4/x^2+7$ has exactly one zero in ($-\infty$,$0$)

I can do it without Rolle's theorem by finding the stationary point which is at about $1.2$ (taking derivative).

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you meant $f(x) = (x^3 + 3)/(x^2 + 7)$?

Comment: No @N.F.Taussig .....no brackets there!

Answer (score 0):

You are right to find that the only stationary point is at "about $1.2$" i.e. $(8/3)^{1/5}$. If $f$ had two zeroes in $(-\infty, 0)$, say, at $a < b$, 
then by Rolle's theorem (since $f(a) = f(b) = 0$) there'd be a stationary point between $a$ and $b$. That means $f'(c) = 0$ for some $c \le b < 0$; but the unique zero of $f'$ is positive!

Oh, and $f(-2) = 0$ shows that $f$ has a zero in $(-\infty, 0)$.